# Comments in config file for batch script

Tags: batch-file, config

I have a config file with some configurations and I read the contents of the file into a batch script using the below command

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (configurations.config) do (set "%%x")
```

There are a few comments (starting with '#') in the config file which I don't want to be read while parsing the file in my batch script.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Sample config file:

> ```
> #This is the comment.
> var1=value1
> var2=value2
> ```

The error I get is

`Environment variable #This is a comment. not defined`

Comment: Please show an example of your config file.

Comment: The first line is the comment starting with #.

Comment: `for /f "eol=# delims=" %%x in (configurations.config) do (set "%%x")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for /F` command features an opetion `eol` to define one character that tells to not process a line if it begins with it (type `for /?` in a command prompt window and read the help text for more):

```
for /f "eol=# delims=" %%x in (configurations.config) do (set "%%x")
```

The default option is `eol=;`. Note that the defined character must be the very first one in the line, there are not even any preceding white-spaces allowed.